# Clarification about javascript callback example

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, callback

I found this example on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_callback1) about js callbacks. It's supposed to output "Goodbye". My question is why isn't "hello" printed first since myFirst() is the first function call followed by mySecond? The code snippet is attached below.

```js
function myDisplayer(some) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = some;
}

function myFirst() {
  myDisplayer("Hello");
}

function mySecond() {
  myDisplayer("Goodbye");
}

myFirst();
mySecond();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Function Sequence</h2>

<p>JavaScript functions are executed in the sequence they are called.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is. But because you're overwriting the HTML each time you call that function you won't see it. Try `innerHTML += some` instead.

Comment: Your functions are called one after the other with no pause in between. The browser will only show the net result after all the changes to the DOM are complete.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. That clears things up.

Comment: And, FWIW, those are just plain old function calls.  "Callbacks" are a specialized implementation.

Answer (score 1):

the function myfirst is working first then the second function ovewrite it at the same time so you just see goodbye not hello!

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome!